# Why can't I analyze with Stockfish 2.0.1 in Winboard 4.5 beta?

Tags: engines, software, stockfish

I have to ask an engine-related question: after I installed the Stockfish 2.0.1 engine on my Winboard 4.5 beta, I can't analyze with it. What I mean is, it's giving nothing in the engine output; it can only analyze with the default engines that come along with it (Houdini 1.5a, Delfi and Phalanx). What may be the reason?

Comment: Stockfish is up to version 2.2.2 now. Do you have a particular reason for using 2.0.1? (Not that I have any reason to believe the version you're using is causing your particular problem.)

Comment: Thats not the answer of the question i asked, any other answers welcome

Comment: Winboard doesn't seem particularly good for supporting UCI engines. There actually used to be an adapter to convert UCI to winboard called polyglot.

Answer (score 2):

Stockfish is a [UCI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Chess_Interface) engine so it doesn't understand [xboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xboard) as they are different protocols. As user @WesFreeman mentioned in the comments, polyglot is an adapter that can get UCI working under Xboard/Winboard. Perhaps visiting the Winboard Startup Dialog or reading the help file may assist you in resolving this issue.

Winboard can also execute polyglot internally if you use -fUCI in the command line, i.e.

`xboard -fUCI -fcp stockfish -sUCI -scp stockfish`

To download the required programs, you can type:

`sudo aptitude install xboard polyglot stockfish`